# Uncaught TypeError: text.select is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement copy to clipboard feature using javascript which is meant to copy the text in the text area when the copy button is clicked by the user. This is the code from script which is meant to do this feature.

```
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('js-copyBtn');

for(var i=0; i < item.length; i++){
    item[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){

        var text = document.getElementsByClassName('js-text');
        text.select();

        try{
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';    
            console.log('Copy was ' + msg);  
       } catch(err) {  
         console.log('Oops, unable to copy');  
       }  
    });
}
```

However when i run this, i am getting an error on google chrome console saying **Uncaught TypeError: text.select is not a function**. I have also tested this on other browsers but getting the same result. Anyone else came across this problem ?

Comment: not really a duplicate... a general answer about the entire ecosystem is **not at all useful** when looking for a *specific* behavior on a *specific* api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a `HTMLCollection` of found elements not an individual element. A HTMLCollection indeed does not have a `select` function.

You probably want the first element in the collection

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('js-text');
text[0].select();
```

Comment: I have tried doing it like that same error unfortunately

Comment: @r1993 jsfiddle or it didnt happen!

Comment: i have replaced it with text[0].select(); but was giving same error

Comment: @r1993 - [rubbish it works fine!](https://jsfiddle.net/46mzgbur/). As I said, reproduce your problem in jsfiddle or similar and I can tell you what you've done wrong. Otherwise its pure guesswork.

Comment: I have replicated my code on jsfiddle  and it only works for the first element only

Comment: @r1993 well, yeah - that was kind of the point of this answer. If you want the second one, then its `text[1]`, third is `text[2]` etc. Once again, if you provide a [mcve] with your actual problem, you'll get better answers and no 3x downvotes.

Comment: Thank you and I understand it will work by doing setting the element you want to get e.g. text[2],text[4]. But i will need to do it for all elements. Would i just iterate through the elements same as how i done it for 'js-copyBtn' ?

Comment: @r1993 no. That would be crazy. Surely there must be a link between your copy button and the text you want to copy?

Comment: At the moment i have several text areas in my webpage along with several buttons, all textareas assigned with one class (js-text) and all buttons assigned with another(js-copyBtn)

Comment: @r1993 I can only suggest a [mcve] a certain number of times before I go blue in the face.

Comment: Its working fine how its supposed to. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Jamiec How does one find out if an object "has" a select function? I'm trying to do this same thing on a <Button> but get the same select() is not a function message.

Comment: @aGuy `if(myObject.select)` - you can test the existence of a function  using the name without parentheses.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this problem today and felt frustrated just as you when the marked answer didn't work for me.
After some additional thinking i realised my problem was trying to paste into paragraph element `<p></p>`.
When I changed it to textarea it worked well.
So you indeed had a problem with the access to the array but when you finally got to the specific element you should have made sure its an editable element.

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select

Answer (score 1):

The `.select()` method does indeed retrieve the text from a field. However, you are trying to run it on an array of elements `var text = document.getElementsByClassName('js-text');`. This method returns an array of all elements with that class name.

If there is only one such element, you could use the array indexer to retrieve the first one. `var text = document.getElementsByClassName('js-text')[0];`.

Alternatively, if there is only one such element, you might consider giving this element an `id` and using `document.getElementById()` which will only return one element. (An ID should be unique on the page)

Comment: reason for using getElementsByClassName is because my webpage has more than one copy to clipboard feature, so i have given all the textareas same class names

Comment: I know this will work just for one element, but then I going to have to give unique id's for all the elements and have multiple elements

Answer (score 1):

getElementByClassName returns an array of elements
So, you have to use text[0].select();

Answer (score 1):

It seems that only textarea can use execCommand, so I think you should use navigator instead.

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyTarget);
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Running this by itself with get you an error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, set an onclick button or link or div, pass the unique id into the function calling the class of the input where the value is, the input would also be unique by class with an id attached.

```
 <a onclick="copytoclipboard(<?php echo $postid['streamitem_id'] ?>)">Copy Link</a>
    <input type="text" value="singlepost.php?postid=<?php echo $postid['streamitem_id'] ?>"
 class="copyclip<?php echo $postid['streamitem_id'] ?>" id="myInput">
```

We then have the copytoclipboard code grabbing the unique id from the onclick. Classnames with different ids are unique so they are an Array of items, this can be search by adding the [0] to the searching of all elements that are the same by name but unique by number in this case.

```
  <script>
/* Copy text to clipboard for single posts from the dropdown post menu */

    function copytoclipboard(streamitem_id) {
      /* Get the text field */
      var streamitem_id=streamitem_id;
      var copyText = document.getElementsByClassName('copyclip'+streamitem_id)[0];
    
      /* Select the text field */
      copyText.select();
    
      /* Copy the text inside the text field */
      document.execCommand("copy");
    
      /* Alert the copied text */
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    }
    </script>
```